# Clarification on steps creating Database Replication Definition

Tags: replication, sybase, sybase-ase

I am being asked to create database replication definitions for a couple of databases (around 20 databases). I just wanted to clarify is the below-mentioned steps are the correct steps to be carried out?
Let's says 'customer' is one of my database.

1. Set ddl in tran to true
   `sp_dboption customer,"ddl in tran", true`
2. Mark the primary database using sp_reptostandby
   `sp_reptostandby customer,'all'`
3. Set the RepAgent parameter send warm standby xacts to true
   `sp_config_rep_agent customer,'send warm standby xacts', 'true'`
4. Create db repdef/subs
   `create database replication definition db_repdef_customer
   with primary at DS.customer
   replicate DDL
   replicate system procedures
   go`
   `create subscription db_sub_customer
   for database replication definition db_repdef_customer
   with primary at DS.customer
   with replicate at DS2.customer1
   without materialization
   go`

(Note: DS.customer and DS2.customer1 are ASE-ASE replication)

After I have followed the above steps to create db repdef/subs, I hit a lot of permission issues on my replication ID to do INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operators on those tables I did not setup table replication yet. Further check on these tables in my 'customer' database (ex. I tried to do insert/update/delete operations manually on tables without setting table repdef, I realised that the data replication is working for all the tables under the 'customer' database with/without I setup table replication. Is this normal? Any steps I have missed out? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 not needed and not normally recommended as it can lead to contention issues on system tables

setp 3 is needed if you want to replicate DDL and system procs (which coincides with what you've got in step 4 - replicate DDL/sysprocs)

`create sub` should be step 5

`check sub` should be step 6

step 7 would be sending a `rs_ticket` from the PDB and making sure it arrives in RDB's `rs_ticket_history` table

make sure your maintuser (in RDB) is aliased to `dbo` to get around permissions issues

Comment: What about Step2? Shall I mark my primary database using sp_reptostandby <primary db>, 'all'? What do you mean by `check sub` in Step6? For Step7, would you please advise how could I send the rs_ticket from PDB?

Comment: you can mark the primary db or you can mark each table, it's your call; `check subscription` command is used to verify subscription is actually created; see documentation for the `rs_ticket` stored proc (installed in PDB when you create your PDB connection), eg, `rs_ticket 'test'` should get replicated into RDB's `rs_ticket_history` table if everything setup correctly

Comment: But if I mark for each table, the DDL commands will not get replicated to my replicate database even there are database replication definitions and subs are created on my primary database replication definition.